# Why do I get jQuery reference error / undefined when changing name of plugin file?

Tags: plugins, jquery

I have two sites which I've copied a plugin from the first site and then altered the plugin and changed the name of plugins directoy and class name.

Like from:

```
old_xplugin
```

In the root of this plugin I have file called `old_xplugin.php` and class name equiavivalent: `class old_xplugin`

TO

`new_xplugin` (now with modifications of the old xplugin)
In the root of this plugin I now a have file called `new_xplugin.php` and class name equiavivalent: `class new_xplugin`

Everything works until I change the name of the folder. (I can change name of the plugin, and the class name without problem).

But when I change the name of the folder I get jQuery reference eror: not defined. **Why isn't jQuery loaded when change of the plugins folder?**

This is the structure of the plugin file(s):

**main plugin file** (new_xplugin.php). These things are not changed after copying the plugin.

```
public function __construct() {                        
    //Iniate jquery and css
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'js_css' ) );                             
}

public function js_css() {                       
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wtfjs',
        plugins_url( '/js/wtf.js' , __FILE__) 
    );        
}
```

**wtf.js**

```
jQuery(function ($) {    //Wordpress says: jQuery reference error: undefined.
//code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea why the change of folder name makes a difference, but you should add jquery as dependency in your enqueue

```
wp_enqueue_script(
        'wtfjs',
        plugins_url( '/js/wtf.js' , __FILE__),
        array('jquery')
    );
```

Comment: Sorry but it did not work. Same error.

Comment: you should check if jquery is being loaded

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mark Kaplun that spotted the actual issue. jQuery did not load before wp_enque_script was executed. So I hooked the function `js_css()` into init like this:

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'js_css' ) );
```

and that solved the problem! :-)

(Very strange that this even worked on site1 though)